# No se controlo nullreference exception c#

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 class Vehiculos
    {
        public string matricula, marca, modelo;
        public int año, cantidadpuertas;

        public double costodiario;

        public string Matricula
    {
        get { return matricula; }
        set { matricula = value; }
    }
    public string Marca
    {
        get { return marca; }
        set { marca = value; }
    }
    public string Modelo
    {
        get { return modelo; }
        set { modelo = value; }
    }
    public int Año
    {
        get { return año; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 2017)
                año = value;
            else
                throw new Exception("No se trabaja con vehículos que aun no se construyeron");
        }
    }
    public int Cantidadpuertas
    {
        set
        {
            if (value < 2)
                throw new Exception("El vehículo tiene que tener mínimo 2 puertas");
            else
                cantidadpuertas = value;

        }
        get { return cantidadpuertas; }
    }
    //public int Digitos
    //{
    //    get { return digitos; }
    //    set { digitos = value; }
    //}
    public double Costodiario
    {
        get { return costodiario; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 25)
                throw new Exception("El costo diario mínimo es de 25 dólares");
            else
                costodiario = value;
        }
    }

    public Vehiculos(string mat, string mar, string mo, int a, int cant, double costo)
    {
        Matricula = mat;
        Marca = mar;
        Modelo = mo;
        Año = a;
        Cantidadpuertas = cant;
    //    Digitos = dig;
        Costodiario = costo;
    }
}
```

Clase alquiler:

```
 class Alquiler
{
    public DateTime fecha1;
    public DateTime fecha2;
    Vehiculos unv;
    Clientes uncl;

    public DateTime Fecha1
    {
        get { return fecha1; }
        set { fecha1 = value; }
    }
    public DateTime Fecha2
    {
        get { return fecha2; }
        set { fecha2 = value; }
    }
        public Alquiler(DateTime f1, DateTime f2, Vehiculos unve, Clientes uncli)
        {
            Fecha1 = f1;
            Fecha2 = f2;
            if (unve == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("unve es requerido");
                unv = unve;

            if (uncli == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("uncli es requerido");
                uncl = uncli;
        }
    public double CalcularAlquiler()
    {
        double costoTotalAlq = 0;
        costoTotalAlq = ((fecha2.Day - fecha1.Day) * unv.costodiario);
        return costoTotalAlq;
    }

    public virtual string MostrarAlquiler()
    {
        return "FECHA DE INICIO ALQUILER : " + fecha1 + " " + "FECHA FIN DE ALQUILER : " + fecha2; 
    }
}
```