# No se controló NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, excepciones

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con C#, pero me da el siguiente error:

> No se controló NullReferenceException
>
> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

como se puede ver en esta imagen:

[image: Captura de pantalla del error]

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema? Éste es el código de mi proyecto:

Clase Alquiler

```
class Alquiler
{
    public DateTime fecha1;
    public DateTime fecha2;
    Vehiculos unv;
    Clientes uncl;

    public DateTime Fecha1
    {
        get { return fecha1; }
        set { fecha1 = value; }
    }
    public DateTime Fecha2
    {
        get { return fecha2; }
        set { fecha2 = value; }
    }

    public Alquiler(DateTime f1, DateTime f2, Vehiculos unve, Clientes uncli)
    {
        Fecha1 = f1;
        Fecha2 = f2;
        if (unve == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("unve es requerido");
            unv = unve;

        if (uncli == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("uncli es requerido");
            uncl = uncli;
    }

    public double CalcularAlquiler()
    {
        double costoTotalAlq = 0;
        costoTotalAlq = ((fecha2.Day - fecha1.Day) * unv.costodiario);
        return costoTotalAlq;
    }

    public virtual string MostrarAlquiler()
    {
        return "FECHA DE INICIO ALQUILER : " + fecha1 + " " + "FECHA FIN DE ALQUILER : " + fecha2; 
    }
}
```

Clase vehiculos:

```
class Vehiculos
{
    public string matricula, marca, modelo;
    public int año, cantidadpuertas;
    //public int digitos;
    public double costodiario;

    public string Matricula
    {
        get { return matricula; }
        set { matricula = value; }
    }
    public string Marca
    {
        get { return marca; }
        set { marca = value; }
    }
    public string Modelo
    {
        get { return modelo; }
        set { modelo = value; }
    }
    public int Año
    {
        get { return año; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 2017)
                año = value;
            else
                throw new Exception("No se trabaja con vehículos que aun no se construyeron");
        }
    }
    public int Cantidadpuertas
    {
        set
        {
            if (value < 2)
                throw new Exception("El vehículo tiene que tener mínimo 2 puertas");
            else
                cantidadpuertas = value;

        }
        get { return cantidadpuertas; }
    }
    //public int Digitos
    //{
    //    get { return digitos; }
    //    set { digitos = value; }
    //}
    public double Costodiario
    {
        get { return costodiario; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 25)
                throw new Exception("El costo diario mínimo es de 25 dólares");
            else
                costodiario = value;
        }
    }

    public Vehiculos(string mat, string mar, string mo, int a, int cant, double costo)
    {
        Matricula = mat;
        Marca = mar;
        Modelo = mo;
        Año = a;
        Cantidadpuertas = cant;
    //    Digitos = dig;
        Costodiario = costo;
    }
```

Éste es mi Program:

```
 Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("            REALIZAR ALQUILER");
                    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------\n");
                    Console.Write("Ingrese cédula de indentidad : ");
                    cedula = Console.ReadLine();
                    Clientes n = emp.Buscar(cedula);
                    Console.Write("\n" + "Ingrese la mátricula del vehículo a alquilar");
                    Console.Write("\n" + "Mátricula : ");
                    matricula = Console.ReadLine();
                    Vehiculos k = emp.Buscarr(matricula);
                    if (n == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n"+ "El cliente no esta registrado");
                        if (k == null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "No existe el vehículo");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n" + "Ingrese fecha de recogida del vehículo");
                        Console.Write("\n" + "Ingrese fecha inicio alquiler : ");
                        fecha1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("\n" + "Ingrese la fecha de devolucioón del vehículo");
                        Console.Write("\n" + "Ingrese fecha fin alquiler : ");
                        fecha2 = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
                        Alquiler alq = new Alquiler(fecha1, fecha2, k, n);
                        emp.Alquilar(alq);
                        Console.WriteLine("El costo total del alquiler es de : " + alq.CalcularAlquiler().ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Se agrego correctamente el alquiler");
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
```

Y acá tengo el buscar de emp:

```
 public Vehiculos Buscarr(string mat)
    {
        Vehiculos v = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lista[i] is Vehiculos)
            {
                if (((Vehiculos)lista[i]).Matricula == mat)
                {
                    v = (Vehiculos)lista[i];
                    i = lista.Count;
                }
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: @Elner ahi estan mis clases

Comment: ¿En dónde se está disparando la excepción? Tienes throw en tu clase, pero ¿tienes catch en donde usas las clases y llamas dichos métodos?

Comment: En que liena de tu codigo lanza la excepcion el depurador?

Comment: Ah lo tengo que disparar en el program, ahi edito y agrego lo que tengo en el program

Comment: Tienes que ser más explícito, no detallas dónde genera el error ni el resultado esperado ni información más útil, por favor date una vuelta en [ask] y recuerda la parte del "mínimo" en cuanto a un [mcve].

Comment: Esta pregunta es un duplicado de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92750/no-se-controlo-nullreference-exception-c

Comment: Por favor, no dupliques preguntas. Edita la pregunta que quieras mantener, (para que tenga toda la información necesaria para responderla: código, descripción del problema, mensajes de error...) y elimina la otra. Dime si necesitas ayuda con esto.

Comment: Perdón no sabia, si la verdad que no se sale, me dijeron que k es null pero como hago para que k no sea null

Comment: He combinado ambas respuestas bajo ésta (que era más completa) y la he editado para traer un detalle que estaba en la otra y no aquí.

Answer (score 2):

El objeto `Vehiculo` que envias en el constructor se esta pasando como null e intentando acceder a la propiedad `costodiario` lanza `NullReferenceException`. Asegurate que no se le este pasando null.

Te recomiendo que cuando una clase se compone de varios objetos, lo mejor es verificar que todos objetos no sean null y asi aseguras que todos los metodos y servicios de clase dispongan de un objeto con valor:

```
public Alquiler(DateTime d1, DateTime d2, Vehiculos unve, Clientes uncli)
{
  if(unve == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("unve es requerido");
  if(uncli == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("uncli es requerido");

  //...
}
```

Comment: @Elner me sigue tirando el mismo error

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y publica el codigo, no la imagen, de la clases `Alquier` y Vehiculo para poder ayudarte mejor y como la utilizas.

Comment: @Elner no me deja editar creo una pregunta nueva

Comment: No. La marcaran como repetida. La clase Alquiler tiene mas de 1 constructor?

Comment: No, tiene uno solo

Comment: @Elner ahi edite

Comment: El error te lo sigue lanzando en el mismo lugar?

Comment: No,  me lo lanza en el thrown que agregue, en el throw de vehiculos que me pasaste

Comment: Te esta pasando lo que mencione en mi respuesta. Estas enviando una instancia de `Vehiculo` nula al constructor de` Alquiler`.

Comment: vos decis que k es null?

Comment: Suponiendo que `k` sea la variable que envias al constructor de alquiler. Sí, es null.

Comment: ah bien, entonces tengo que hacer que k no sea null

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que k es nulo y sólo lo validas si n es null.

```
Vehiculos k = emp.Buscarr(matricula);
```

En el código de tus clases no tienes errores.

Comment: Que tendria que hacer para que k no sea null? @GonzaloBustamante

Comment: Debes fijarte en el método Buscarr del objeto emp. Publica ese método en tu pregunta, pero no hagas duplicados.

Comment: Ahi pase el codigo, tengo vehiculos v = null;

Comment: Reemplaza la siguiente línea en tu código:

`Vehiculos k = emp.Buscarr(matricula);`

por 

`Vehiculos k = new Vehiculos();`

Recuerda pasarle los parámetros que te pide al constructor. Si eso funciona es porque el método Buscarr() está retornando null.

Comment: No funciona! @GonzaloBustamante

Comment: Eso es porque nunca cumple las condiciones del if de tu consulta. Pueden ser varios motivos: 1) Que lista[] esté vacío 2) Que lista[] no contenga objetos tipo Vehiculos 3) Que simplemente la matrícula no se encuentre dentro de lista[]
De todas maneras, cuando llamas al método Buscarr() te recomiendo hacerlo dentro de un try{} catch{} y verificar que lo que retornas no es null.

Answer (score 1):

No hay error en el código que publicaste, por ende, el problema debe estar en la instancia del objeto Alquiler.

Asegurate de instanciarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
DateTime f1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime f2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
Vehiculos veh = new Vehiculos("mat", "mar", "mo", 5, 4, 15000);
Clientes cli = new Clientes();
Alquiler objeto = new Alquiler(f1, f2, veh, cli);
double resultado = objeto.CalcularAlquiler();
```

Aclarar que hay muchas formas de escribir este código, esta es sólo una propuesta.

Es posible que le estés pasando un objeto tipo Vehiculos no instanciado.

Saludos.

Comment: Fechas nulas? Imposible a menos que  DateTime sea nullable y claramente no lo es.

Comment: Tienes razón. Entonces el objeto Vehículo debe ser nulo. Lo editaré, gracias.